# Creating neural network to solve for equations

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, mathematics

I have a dataset like:

[image]

The v1 variable is a mathematical expression.
Currently, I am using hyperopt to solve for these parameters and am using v1,v2,v3 in regression to predict y and then minimize the RMSE as the objective function.

The values of x, y, and z are from 0-1 and that's how I defined the space.

Will it be possible if we can use a neural network setup to solve for such cases? I would really appreciate it if someone could provide a starting point to solve such a problem.

The reason I would like to switch from Bayesian optimization is because in reality I have 50+ parameters and it is not recommended to solve for so many parameters using a Bayesian approach.

Comment: ANNs can be used (consistently) provided the mapping is one-to-one (ie $y$ is unique given the linear or non-linear equation).

Comment: yeah that condition holds true. It's just how to feed this equation into the model? with hyperopt, i used to take the parameter values, evaluate them and then feed into a regression pipeline.
I can't visualize how to feed this type of equation into an ann

Comment: for example you can evaluate the equation given the values of x,y,z and feed that into the NN